# Simple error on a javascript forloop

Tags: javascript

This was the task

Create an array called names filled with 5 names.
Write a for loop that prints "I know someone called " followed by names[i]. Make sure there's a space between "called" and the name!
Run your code and the five sentences should print out.
Click "Stuck? Get a hint!" for an example of how to write a for loop
Oops, try again. Your code should have printed 'I know someone called AKin ', but didn't. Make sure to type the 'I know someone called ' part exactly right, and don't forget the space between that phrase and the name!

This is my code

```
var names = ["AKin ", "Junior", "Segun ", "Akinola", "You"];
 for (var i =0; i<5; i++){
    console.log("I know someone called " + names[i]);
    }
```

this was the error I got
Oops, try again. Your code should have printed 'I know someone called AKin ', but didn't. Make sure to type the 'I know someone called ' part exactly right, and don't forget the space between that phrase and the name!

Comment: This question is off-topic because it seems like a homework question from someone who just doesn't get it.

Comment: Looks like you're just copy pasting your question from somewhere. Do your homework yourself.

Comment: Firstly, you could change `i < 5` to `i < names.length` to make it more robust, in case you change the number of items in the names array. Secondly, this looks to me like a Codecademy task and unfortunately the errors that the online editor throws are not always reliable. Try reloading your browser if this is the case.

Comment: I am taking a course on codecademy and I have spent the last hour trying to figure out what I missed

Comment: Thank you Micheal I tried everything just now. Still the same error

Comment: maybe they check for [`document.writeln(`](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_doc_writeln.asp) instead of `console.log(`

Answer (score 0):

You code looks correct but it seems like the software that checks it doesn't like part of it.  Look up using the array.length property and see if that works.

https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_length_array.asp